# Use of left join in joining 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

I have 2 Tables namely Area_ Table and PingData_Table

1. Area Table has the list of the areas along with the Area ID and Area Name

```
 AreaId | AreaName |  isActive
   1    |Jumbo House| 1
   2    | DCC       | 1
   3    |Dubai Mall | 1
```

2. Ping Table has the ping made by devices installed on different area location with a different ID. I ping each device every 5 mins and update the status in the table.

> Please note that no row is inserted in the table if the ping is
>   unsuccessful which means the device is inactive

```
pkey  | AreaId  |   UpdatedOn
411   |   1     | 2018-08-08 21:54:24.810
547   |   1     | 2018-08-08 10:39:21.987
1046  |   1     | 2018-08-08 00:09:57.843
```

Now I want to show the above data in the following format.

***Status of devices for 8 August 2018***

```
Areaid | Name           |   Status
1      |Jumbo House     | Active
2      |DCC             | Not Active between 00:00 hrs to 23:00 hrs
3      |Dubai Mall      | Not Active between XX:00 hrs to XX:00 hrs
```

for all the Areas.

What I have tried till now is:

```
CREATE TABLE #TimeTable (hrs DATETIME)
CREATE TABLE #pingData (pid INT , areaId INT , pingTime DATETIME)
DECLARE 
  @start DATETIME = '2018-08-08 0:00', 
  @end   DATETIME =  '2018-08-08 23:00';
WITH x(n) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @start, @end) + 1) 
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY [object_id]
)
INSERT INTO #TimeTable(hrs) SELECT t = DATEADD(HOUR, n-1, @start) FROM x ORDER BY t;
INSERT INTO #pingData ( areaId  , pingTime ) 
SELECT DISTINCT [AreaId],CAST(FORMAT([UpdatedOn],'yyyy-MM-dd HH')+':00:00.000' as datetime) as pingtime 
FROM [dbo].[Pingtable] 
where UpdatedOn > @start and UpdatedOn <= @end
select  a.areaId , p.pingTime,t.hrs , a.AreaName , CASE WHEN  p.pingTime IS NULL THEN 'INACTIVE' ELSE 'ACTIVE' END as DeviceStatus
from Area_Table a   
left  join #pingData p on a.areaId = p.AreaId
left   join #TimeTable t  on p.pingTime = t.hrs 
ORDER BY a.areaId,t.hrs
drop table #TimeTable ;
drop table #pingData ;
```

Please guide me as to how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

you could try like below

```
with ping as    
(
select AreaId,min(UpdatedOn) min_updatetime,
max(UpdatedOn) max_updatetime,
convert(date,UpdatedOn) as day_of_month
from ping_table
group by AreaId,convert(date,UpdatedOn)
) select A.AreaId,A.AreaName,
  case when P.AreaId is null then 'Not Active' else 'Active' end as Status
  from AreaTable A left join ping P  on A.AreaId=P.AreaId
```

Comment: Got an error Ping.AreaId is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @ThugsofHindustan where you find Ping.AreaId? i have not used my query that id

Comment: The areaid when we are selecting column from the ping table

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ @ThugsofHindustan create your table here and show where error thrown

Comment: Please have a look https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8e6f9e931e31fa1e0d71d0f67ec42d3

Comment: Also as discussed with @sanal
I need to have this analysis on a hourly basis . and between a time range Eg : 2018/8/8 00:00 HRS to 2018/8/8 23:59 HRS Also I wanna know if the device was switched off or unavailable during any particular time during that time range